# what is the kappa variable (BayesianOptimization)

Tags: optimization, bayesian, hyperparameters, scikit-optimize

I read some posts and tutorials about `BayesianOptimization` and I never saw explanation about `kappa` variable.

- What is the `kappa` variable ?
- How can it help us ?
- How this values can influence the `BayesianOptimization` process ?

Comment: https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization/blob/91441fe4002fb6ebdb4aa5e33826230d8df560d0/bayes_opt/bayesian_optimization.py#L236

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `kappa` parameter, along with `xi`, is used to control how much the Bayesian optimization acquisition function balances exploration and exploitation.

Higher `kappa` values mean more exploration and less exploitation and vice versa for low values.  Exploration pushes the search towards unexplored regions and exploitation focuses on results in the vicinity of the current best results by penalizing for higher variance values.

It may be beneficial to begin with default `kappa` values at the start of optimization and then lower values if you reduce the search space.

In scikit-optimize, `kappa` is only used if the acquisition function `acq_func` is set to “LCB” and `xi` is used when `acq_func` is “EI” or “PI” where LCB is Lower Confidence Bound, EI is Expected Improvement and PI is Probability of Improvement.

Similarly for the BayesianOptimization package:

```
 acq: {'ucb', 'ei', 'poi'}
            The acquisition method used.
                * 'ucb' stands for the Upper Confidence Bounds method
                * 'ei' is the Expected Improvement method
                * 'poi' is the Probability Of Improvement criterion.
```

[Mathematical details on acquisition functions](https://www.cse.wustl.edu/%7Egarnett/cse515t/spring_2019/files/lecture_notes/12.pdf)

Note, the [BayesianOptimization](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization/blob/91441fe4002fb6ebdb4aa5e33826230d8df560d0/bayes_opt/bayesian_optimization.py#L236) package and [scikit-optimize](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/modules/generated/skopt.acquisition.gaussian_lcb.html) use different default `kappa` values: 2.576 and 1.96 respectively.

There is a decent [exploration vs exploitation example in the scikit-optimize docs](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/auto_examples/exploration-vs-exploitation.html).

There is a similar [BayesianOptimization exploration vs exploitation example notebook](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization/blob/master/examples/exploitation_vs_exploration.ipynb).

FWIW I've used both packages and gotten OK results.  I find the scikit-optimize [plotting functions](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/modules/plots.html#plots) to be useful when fine tuning the parameter search space.